# python flask 404 not found

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask development, and can't the following application work. I wish to declare the Flask app in run.py, and import it in the other packages such as myapp below. I design it this way is because there are more than one independent applications/packages. I get 404 when trying to access the url ".../hello". Where am I wrong? Thanks!

The project layout is look like this:

```
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── myapp.py
└── run.py
```

myapp/__init__.py contains:

```
from flask import Flask
my_app = Flask(__name__)
from . import myapp
```

myapp/myapp.py contains:

```
from run import app
@app.route('/hello')
def show_conf2():
    return "Hello, world!"
```

The run.py contains:

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import myapp
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Home route.'
app = Flask(__name__)
http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: what is render_template ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I attempt to implement REST based services.

Comment: In my case I had some url prefixes for some routes using Blueprints and I forgot to add them before making api calls. Realised it after getting completely frustrated. Coding humbles me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared two instances of `Flask`, one in `__init__.py` and another in `run.py`.

Flask official documentation has a tutorial on [how to breakdown a larger application in multiple modules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/#larger-applications).

I have updated your code, filenames and folder structure.

Folder structure:

```
├── application
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
└── run_application.py
```

`run_application.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from application import app

http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

`application/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import application.views
```

`application/views.py`:

```
from application import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Home route.'

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
gevent==1.4.0
greenlet==0.4.15
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.15.2
```

Run command:

```
python run_application.py
```

**Output**:

1. Home route `http://localhost:5000/`

[image: Home route]

2. hello route `http://localhost:5000/hello`

[image: hello route]

### Update

According to [Flask documentation on Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/),

> Flask uses a concept of blueprints for making application components
>   and supporting common patterns within an application or across
>   applications.

Updated the code to facilitate `blueprints`.

Updated Directory Structure:

```
├── application1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── routes.py
├── application2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── routes.py
├── apps.py
└── requirements.txt
```

`apps.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from application1.routes import application1_blueprint
from application2.routes import application2_blueprint


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(application1_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(application2_blueprint)    

http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

`application1/__init__.py`: blank file

`application1/routes.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

application1_blueprint = Blueprint('application1', __name__)

@application1_blueprint.route('/app1')
def application1_index():
    return 'Home route for application1'

@application1_blueprint.route('/hello1')
def hello1():
    return 'Hello World from application1!'
```

`application2/__init__.py`: blank file

`application2/routes.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

application2_blueprint = Blueprint('application2', __name__)

@application2_blueprint.route('/app2')
def application2_index():
    return 'Home route for application2'

@application2_blueprint.route('/hello2')
def hello2():
    return 'Hello World from application2!'
```

**Output:**

`/app1` route from `application1`:

[image: application 1 view]

`/app2` route from `application2`:

[image: application 2 view]

Comment: Thanks! In application, does the module have to be named "views.py"? I'd prefer other more meaningful names in read applications.

Comment: No. You can change `views.py` to any name. In that case change `import application.views` this to `import application.YOUR_FILENAME`. One suggestion though, do not use same folder name and filename like `myapp` and `myapp.py`. It often create confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll test it out shortly. So in a 2nd folder (application2, e.g.), I would say "from application import app" to make other routes in the views.py there? Do I need to claim "app = Flask(__name__)" as well in the __init__.py. My original attempt to define the "app" in the run.py is to facilitate importing it from any arbitrary number of packages next to run.py.

Comment: Can you provide your suggestion on how to make the urls in a 2nd package work? This is the real challenge I encountered. I appreciate your help and sorry for not making the question clear in the first place.

Comment: Updated the answer to use blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I guess you execute the `run.py` in your flask application. In this case your application does NOT define any routing rule. Just modify and put your code into single file and it will be workable

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
#import myapp

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def show_conf2():
    return "Hello, world!"

http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear. The file layout is needed by my project. I can't put everything in one file in real applications. The example I gave above is just to show the problem I have.